# Pandas read_csv() - Can I fix missing values before they are handled by a converter in read_csv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Inside read_csv I am using a custom converter that translates timestamps to integers. The problem is that some of the values that are sent to the converter are bad, meaning either empty strings or non numerically representable strings.

I tried to raise an exception inside the converter whenever those values are detected but that doesn't seem to be working. I am aware of methods like `dropna()` but that can be applied only after the data are loaded into memory. I am also aware of the `na_values` argument but not quite sure how to use it for this purpose.

Is there a way to filter out those bad values before they get sent into the converter?

here is a 10 row sample of the input file with a bad value in the 9th row

```
0:00:00.000 644.2748413
0:00:00.002 644.4001465
0:00:00.004 642.8461914
0:00:00.006 643.7497559
0:00:00.008 644.1955566
0:00:00.010 642.1920166
0:00:00.012 643.4448853
0:00:00.014 #VALUE!
0:00:00.016 644.1955566
0:00:00.018 643.2954102
```

I have also tried to make the converter return `NaN` in case the value cannot be converted but that doesn't work either. I assume the converter does not work completely sequentially on the data and that is also why it's hard to track down in which values it get's stuck by using print statements.

**update2**

As I found out the problem was not in the timestamp (as you can see in the sample file) column that gets processed by the converter, though the error message stated that there was a problem in the line where the converter get's called, and I got confused. So now it's clearer, although I don't know why the misleading error message. I can probably use `na_values` to clear things.

Comment: Can you show content of file? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best approach.

Comment: Why before? What about returning `nan` and dealing with it afterwards?

Comment: Maybe help parameter `na_values` in `read_csv`.

Comment: I updated the question